# Profile date input not working correctly

Tags: bug, stack-exchange, profile-page, dates

Stack overflow asks for a input of YYYY/MM/DD, but it does not take my date, for example 1982/11/21 will get an error message asking for a YYYY/MM/DD input. I do not really care but it does look stupid :D.

Comment: where does it ask for this ?

Comment: Check for trailing white-space, it accepts 1982/11/21 for me.

Comment: @PhaDaPhunk OP: "Profile date input."

Comment: It does not accept "1982/11/21" for me. Copied that just before saving without the "

Comment: I tried with FF17 and Opera 12 btw

Comment: I had no issues copy/pasting your date in there, are your *sure* you typed it correctly?  This hasn't changed in a *very* long time, and this is the only report I've come across of it not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As stated up above the date format you entered is valid. The only way the site wouldn't accept it if you didn't typed it exactly as you said you did or because you have a white space somewhere (the date does not trim the spaces so if you have one it sees `YYYY/MM/DDD` which is invalid).

Comment: I accept this as an answer since it is working now. Still there was a problem, filled in enough date types in my life to understand how to fill this one in. I did not screw up 10 times in a row, i tried to copy/paste it and fill it in manually multiple times.

Today i recorded it for you guys but it seemed to work at once.